# Intellij - Error:java: invalid source release: 1.8

Tags: java, macos, maven, intellij-idea

While trying to run tests, I ran into this compilation error:

[image: invalid source release: 1.8]

I tried researching this on Google and here, and after applying all of the solutions that worked for others this issue still persists.
Here is what I have done so far:

- Preferences -> Java Compiler: set 'project bytecode version' to 1.8

  - I also set the target bytecode version to 1.8 for each individual module as well
- Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner: Set JRE to use Project JDK (which correctly displays as 1.8)
- Project Structure -> Project: set Project SDK to 1.8 and language level to 8
- Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources: set language level to 8 for each module
- Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies: set Module SDK to 1.8

I think this issue may have something to do with a discrepancy between the JDK and the compiler.
When I run `java -version` from the terminal it returns 1.8.0_111. However when I run `javac -version` it returns 1.7.0_79. I looked for ways to force change the javac version to match the java version but nearly all of them reference `update-alternatives` which is not available for Mac OS or removing /usr/bin which is not allowed (even with sudo) on El Capitan.

**Workaround Edit:**
I was able to bypass the issue by going to Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler and changing the compiler from "javac" to "Eclipse" and I am able to compile my project.

Comment: How did you install Java on your Mac?

Comment: I downloaded Java SDK 8u111 directly from Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: And you tried reinstalling again, followed by a reboot, to be safe? Your path and environment variables are getting messed up, seems like

Comment: I tried removing all java versions and then reinstalled 1.8.0_111, then rebooted. It is still coming up with the same error and javac is still 1.7, even though 1.7 should be gone.

Comment: You should provide your "workaround" as an answer below. Even though, I think that is the correct solution, not a workaround at all (Not sure why it says "Eclipse")

Comment: The reason I added it as a workaround is because for this particular project using the Eclipse compiler can be buggy and my team tries to use the javac compiler to avoid issues. But I can add it as an answer for others that might find it helpful to use an alternative compiler.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install jdk1.8.*
2. Change SDK to jdk1.8.*
3. Done

Comment: Thanks, this one worked for me after trying everything else suggested on SO and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change java version at the terminal, try this:
`change-java 8`

Answer (score 1):

On IntelliJ:

- Click on "File" menu
- Click on "Settings" sub-menu.
- On the Settings window, click to expand "Build, Execution, Deployment"
- Expand "Build Tools"
- Click on "Gradle"
- On Gradle JVM, select the Java version you wish to use

[IntelliJ Settings - Gradle Configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f6yS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully compile my project by going into Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler an changing the "use compiler" option from Javac to Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me: 
Under ***Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner***

Change *Run tests using:* from **Platform Test Runner** to **Gradle Test Runner**:

[image]