# New Spring Project Build Failure

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am a total beginner to spring. I have installed jdk and maven…

`echo $JAVA_HOME` shows:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

`$ javac -version` shows:

```
javac 9.0.4
```

`mvn -version` shows:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T08:58:13+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2/libexec
Java version: 9.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

The only thing I have done so far is create a package called "controller" with a "HomeController.java" file inside it, with this code:

```
package com.demo.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){

        return "Hello World.";
    }
}
```

But when I do `mvn spring-boot:run` I get:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.561 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-01-17T13:28:14Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/83M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project demo: Could not exec java: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have not touched spring before so having installed jdk (via java website) and maven (via homebrew) and followed tutorial for setting up spring app inside intellij I don’t know what I have done wrong/not done. I see the error referencing unable to exec java and the link provided states it is a plugin issue, but how do I solve this?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo-spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

[image: Structure]

Comment: have you tried the solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157515/could-not-exec-java-with-springmaven-exit-code-1 The problem sounds very similar

Comment: post your project structure, plz.

Comment: You need download dependencies .

Comment: I added pom and image of file structure.

Comment: Dipak can you explain further please?

Comment: Go to project directory -> open command prompt -> type command -> mvn clean install -> then try to run boot appplication

Comment: one more thing you have change you jdk version in the pom.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all these errors are related to Java 9.

Maven has suggested some changes for Java 9, May be you can use them like:

1. Add Java 9 as properties:

   [image]
2. For Compilation failure, fix ***maven-compiler-plugin***:
   [image]
3. For Test failure, fix ***maven-surefire-plugin***
   [image]
4. For Packaging failure, fix ***maven-jar-plugin*** (optional)
   [image]
5. For Spring boot plugin failure, fix ***spring-boot-maven-plugin***

   [image]

For more informations, go [this](https://blog.frankel.ch/migrating-to-java-9/1/#gsc.tab=0) blog.

Comment: Thank you for this. It solved all the errors it detailed until the last point - where I do `mvn spring-boot:run`. I think I am just going to uninstall java and install 1.8 and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

You current version of jdk is 1.9.0 but in pom.xml it is point to 1.8 so you need to change that version to 1.9.

Below is your version

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Change it to the 1.9

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.9</java.version>
    </properties>

then try to run below command 

mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

Comment: I updated the version in pom to 1.9 and did `mvn clean install` and got `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures.`

Comment: The file it references is massive. But at the top states `Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.553 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.demo.spring.demo.DemoSpringApplicationTests
contextLoads(com.demo.spring.demo.DemoSpringApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.011 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

Comment: go to project directory and try to run mvn clean install command

Comment: I did, like I said it get me the error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures.`

Comment: Of course I am messaging back. It is working fine. I also did `mvn clean install -U` which I read would deal with dependencies. Still same error message though

Comment: Do you see any option in intellij idea to update mvn offline??

Comment: No but it did say "Maven projects need to be imported: Import Changes   Enable Auto-Import" and I selected Enable Auto-Import

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163333/discussion-between-dipak-thoke-and-dan).

Comment: If I do debug in intellij its saying "Error:java: invalid source release: 1.9"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680212/intellij-errorjava-invalid-source-release-1-8 can you please check this.